# How do i use ssh to log into my computer?

Tags: ssh, fedora-11

In the past I've been using putty to ssh into my school's Fedora computers to do HW, but now I recently put Fedora on my computer, and I want make it so that I can ssh to my Fedora computer from my school too.

I looked through a tutorial, and was able to:

- make the private key and public key
- make a passphrase
- move to public key to my school's system
- chmod 700 the public key

Now when I try to ssh into my own computer from school it gives me an error that says I cannot resolve my hostname and name or service unknown.

I don't know what to do from here, the tutorial was no help after this.

Comment: We need to know what's between the two machines in order to tell you what to do.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: FYI, the steps you took would help you to SSH into your school's computer from Fedora. If you want to use public key authentication when SSH'ing into your computer from your school, you'll need to perform the same steps but with the roles of the client and server reversed - i.e. create private and public keys on your school's computer and copy the public key to your home computer. But that is  something you would do only _after_ you have taken the steps in e.g. Darth's answer and ensured that they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to resolve hostname means that the domain you were trying to connect to doesn't actually exist. If it's a home computer and you don't have your own domain set up, then your best bet would be to simply use your IP address (you can find your IP address by going to http://whatismyip.com/ from any computer in your house).

If you have a router, then the IP above is your external IP address, and you would need to forward port 22 in your router to port 22 on the fedora computer.